# Javascript is not working in Rails/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out why the javascript cannot locate the .submit-button from the modal. My javascript is in application.js but I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Am I meant to wrap my JQuery code in something else?

```
**application.js**// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
    import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
    import "controllers"
    import "popper"
    import "bootstrap"
    
    $(document).on("click", ".submit-button", function () {
        alert("click");
    });
```

---

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Welcome! Please Log in</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= simple_form_for(resource, remote: true, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_notification %>
    
                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <%= f.input :email,
                                required: true,
                                autofocus: true,
                                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
                    <%= f.input :password,
                                required: true,
                                hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                                required: true,
                                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up Now", class: 'btn btn-primary submit-button' %>
                </div>
             <% end %>
    
              <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
            <%= button_to(
            "Log Out",
            destroy_user_session_path,
            method: :delete
          ) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?  Is jQuery present as the global `$`?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: What JavaScript approach do you use? importmap / esbuild / webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have comment about importmaps in the top of `application.js`, you use [this library](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails)

You can pin jQuery such way (I took URL from your answer, you can use [from jsDelivr](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.js) or other sources)

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

# ... your existing pins
pin "jquery", to: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
```

and import

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "jquery"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"

$(document).on("click", ".submit-button", function () {
  alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` between the head tags as I was getting the `error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I had gem 'jquery-rails' in my gemfile but not sure why rails is doing this, however problem solved.

Comment: The jquery-rails gem is actually the old assorted Rails javascript helpers from way back before they ditched the jQuery dependency in Rails 5.1 (2017). It should not be used as its barely been updated since then and overlaps with features of Turbo. It also just works with the old Sprockets assets pipeline and not import maps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need jQuery in 2023?

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
  if (!event.target.matches(".submit-button")) return;
  alert("click!");
});
```

The browser API's today are so much better so that it's just as easy to do without it.

If you're doing anything more complex you can use [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/).